# UTF-8 Symbols displaying wrong

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, encoding, utf-8

I have an issue with UTF-8 symbols, such as ☃ - this is being displayed as Â˜Ƒ on the site.

The database, table and column charset is UTF8 and utf8_unicode_ci collation.

I have a header

```
Content-Type => text/html; charset=utf-8
```

and a meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

php.ini has a default encoding of utf-8

I have the following lines in my my.cnf file

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
default-character-set=utf8
default-collation=utf8_general_ci
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'

[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

All files are with a UTF-8 encoding. 
When I output the same data in the Mysql Cli everything's OK, but when its displayed on the page, symbols are messed up.

I'm out of options here, please help :(

Comment: I don't know CI specifically, but likely you need to set `encoding` to `utf8` somewhere in your CI database connection configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Write this line on root/index.php, and see if it works:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

This will set the header to utf. it should be the first line before any white-spaces or anything.